# Visual Studio 2015 with C# Set Class as Startup Object

Tags: c#, winforms

Anyone can tell me how can i set a Class as Startup Object?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with C#.

**UPDATE:**
I am using Windows Form as Host.

Comment: What is your host ? Windows Forms ? Console ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Program.cs` class and change

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
Application.Run(new WhateverClassNameYouHave());
```

Based on your comments, you can decide in `program.cs` which form you want to launch:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Form toBeLaunched = null;

     // Write whatever code here to decide which form to open
     // if(x > y)
         //toBeLaunched = new Form1();
     // else
         // toBeLaunched = new Form2();


     Application.Run(toBeLaunched);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error :cannot convert from 'Sample_Project.My_CLass' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' . Sorry I am just new here.

Comment: @bernzkie You can only set a `Form` as your `Startup Page`. You can't set a normal `class`! It is `windows forms`, you need to show something on the screen. Else, Create a `Windows Console Application` Project.

Comment: SO there's no way i can set my Class as Startup Object?

Comment: Why do you need to set a class and not a form as your startup project ? Don't you want something to be shown on the screen ?

Comment: No, I would like to check if a text file contain of the String ("Hello World"), If not then i will call a form with Textbox then write the given input from Textbox  on text file, I don't want to show the Main Form if the text file has no string. :-/

Comment: You can write this code in program.cs before `Application.Run(new MyForm())`; Or better you can call your class from their and decide which `form` you want to launch.

Comment: @bernzkie check the edited answer to see how you can do that.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much @user3185569 who ever you are. You help me a lot. Thank You!!! Sorry for my dump question.

Answer (score 1):

Entry point to *any* C# desktop application is `static void Main(string[] args)`, typically residing in the `Program.cs` file. You'll need to instantiate your class from there.

Within a Windows Forms project, you can specify which form is as a parameter to `Application.Run(form)` method:

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Keep in mind, this *must be a form* - that is, a class that inherits `Windows.Forms.Form`